# JavaFX Application Thread Out Of Memory Error: Java Heap Space

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

In my javafx project, i have a gridpane of cells with a main character and four enemies. The main character moves when the arrow keys are hit. The problem is that when the board is 4*4 and I hit an arrow key, it takes two seconds for the main character to move, and when the size of board is 10*10, after the first two arrow key hits nothing happens, and the third time gives me  JavaFX Application Thread Out Of Memory Error: Java Heap Space.
I have no idea what is causing this problem. What object is getting newed so many times it fills all the RAM? Any solutions for how to fix this code?

```
package project.view;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;


import project.controller.GameController;
import project.model.*;
import project.transition.FlipTransition;
import project.view.components.CardView;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.DOWN;

public class GameView extends Application implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
    public GridPane gameBoard;
    public BorderPane borderPane;
    private static CardView[][] cards = new CardView[GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().getBoard().length][GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().getBoard()[0].length()];
    public GameBoard gameBoardInCode;
    public static Stage stage;
    public static Scene scene;
    public static Timeline timeline;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/project/fxml/game_board.fxml")))
        GameView.stage = stage;
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/project/fxml/game_board.fxml");
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        System.out.println(url.toString());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        GameView.scene = scene;
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(key -> {
            if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || key.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN || key.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT || key.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                moveMainCharacterInView(key);
                return;
            }

        });
        stage.setTitle("New Game");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        int rows = GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().getBoard().length;
        int columns = GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().getBoard()[0].length();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                CardView rectangle = getUpdatedCardRectangle(i, j);
                gameBoard.add(rectangle, j, i);
                cards[i][j] = rectangle;
            }
        }
        GridPane.setHalignment(gameBoard, HPos.CENTER);
        gameBoard.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    public static void updateBoard() {
        int rows = GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().getBoard().length;
        int columns = GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().getBoard()[0].length();
        GridPane gameBoard = (GridPane) stage.getScene().lookup("#1");
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                CardView rectangle = getUpdatedCardRectangle(i, j);
                gameBoard.add(rectangle, j, i);
                cards[i][j] = rectangle;
            }
        }
        gameBoard.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    public static void moveMainCharacterInView(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            System.out.println("UP");
            if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().size() != 0) {
                GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMainCharacter().moveMainCharacter("up");
                updateBoard();
            }
        } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("RIGHT");
            if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().size() != 0) {
                GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMainCharacter().moveMainCharacter("right");
                updateBoard();
            }
        } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
            System.out.println("LEFT");
            if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().size() != 0) {
                GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMainCharacter().moveMainCharacter("left");
                updateBoard();
            }
        } else if (event.getCode() == DOWN) {
            System.out.println("DOWN");
            if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().size() != 0) {
                GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMainCharacter().moveMainCharacter("down");
                updateBoard();
            }
        }
    }
    private static CardView getUpdatedCardRectangle(int i, int j) {
        CardView rectangle = new CardView();
        Card card = Card.getAllCards()[i][j];
       
            if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("2")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.Enemy_1, i, j);
            } else if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("3")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.Enemy_2, i, j);
            } else if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("4")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.Enemy_3, i, j);
            } else if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("5")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.Enemy_4, i, j);
            } else if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("6")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.MAINCHARACTER, i, j);
            } else if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("*")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.EMPTY, i, j);
            } else if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("1")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.UNPASSABLE, i, j);
            } else if (GameBoard.getGameBoards().get(0).getMazeCreator().giveContentOfBoard(i, j, j + 1).equals("0")) {
                card = new Card(CellSituation.PASSABLE, i, j);
            }
        
        rectangle.setFill(card.getFrontImage());
        if (card.getCellSituation().equals(CellSituation.PASSABLE) || card.getCellSituation().equals(CellSituation.UNPASSABLE)) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 1) {
                rectangle.setHeight(3);
                rectangle.setWidth(50);
            }
            if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 0) {
                rectangle.setHeight(50);
                rectangle.setWidth(3);
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) {
                rectangle.setHeight(3);
                rectangle.setWidth(3);
            }
        } else {
            rectangle.setHeight(50);
            rectangle.setWidth(50);
        }
        rectangle.setI(card.getI());
        rectangle.setJ(card.getJ());
        return rectangle;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Escape "4*4" as "4\*4" to prevent italics from showing.`

Comment: [mcve] please ..